# Can someone help me or give me some tips to make this page responsive?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive

I'm still beginner in CSS,and I don't know exactly why this page doesn't have any responsiveness.
Can someone help in this,or just give some tips how to make it responsive.
I tried with some `@media queries`,but I wasn't satisfied with the result,and I think there are other solutions for this.
I would be very grateful,if you guys could help me.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.nameContainer {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    display: inherit;
}
.textContainer {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    display: inline-table;
    font-size: 47px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 124px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.previewImage {
    height: 450px;
    width: 450px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.textContainer span {
    display: contents;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.CategoryContainer {
    display: flex;
}
.CategoryContainer p {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 10px 2px;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-size: 23px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.CategoryContainer p {
    background-color: dodgeblue;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 10px 2px;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-size: 23px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.descContainer {
  display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: normal;
    min-width: 700px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="previewImage">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" title="text" draggable="false">
                <div class="textContainer" draggable="false">
                    <div class="nameContainer"><span draggable="false">Some text here</span></div>
                    <div class="CategoryContainer"><p>Some text</p></div>
          <div class="descContainer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</p>
</div>    
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Although your inquiry does not address a specific responsive design question, after review of your code I realized that you probably want `.previewImage{ display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; }`. Of course, that does not address your other CSS issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving the img it's own class and set it's height and width to percentage. Since you've set the main container to a fixed height and width, it won't be responsive. Also, you will have to use media queries and adjust each class to the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from media queries, I'd recommend avoiding using the sizes in pixels and using instead relative css units such as `em` or `rem`, so the font sizes, heights and widths are scalable. Read more about this here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp